# javascript new array without duplicates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-state

hmm.. I have tried a few things but cant get this to work... I know it should be simpler than I am making it.

I want to create an array without duplicates. Can you help me?

```
useEffect(() => {
    allBands.forEach(band => {
        if(!availableGenres.includes(band.bandGenre)){
            setAvailableGenres(genres => [...genres, band.bandGenre])  
        }
    })
}, [allBands])
```

Comment: Can you provide `allBands`, `genres`, and `availableGenres` please? We don't know what structures you're working with.

Comment: The answer below works -- But I am curious if you had another idea. allBands is an array of objects that each have a bandGenre. I was using the forEach() method to extract the genre from each object in the allBands array. -- availableGenres and setAvailableGenres are part of the useState in react where I was storing the extracted genres. 'genres' is the updator for the state. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might recommend using the built-in `Set` object to track unique genres. Once your `Set` has all the genres, you can use the spread operator (`...`) to convert it back into an array and set the available genres.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const genres = new Set();
  allBands.forEach(band => {
    genres.add(band.bandGenre);
  })
  setAvailableGenres([...genres]);
}, [allBands])
```

Comment: Wow! I have never heard of this one. It works! --  I am reading about it now - I see that it automatically checks to make sure each value is unique? Are there any downsides to using new Set() ?  Thanks so much for showing me this.

Comment: One downside is that `Set`s are unordered.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not misunderstanding your data structure, you might try this.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setAvailableGenres(genres => [
    ...genres, 
    ...allBands.map(band => band.bandGenre).filter(bandGenre => !genres.includes(bandGenre))
])}, [allBands])
```